# Data does not display in the Kendo MVC Grid ASP.NET Core

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc, grid

I am trying out fairly basic data binding with hardcoded data using Kendo Grid using MVC - ASP.NET Core. The Grid renders fine, and the .read method is called as well and returns JSON; however, the data does not display in the grid. I tried to see if the aspnet-mvc.js loads fine. I don't see any errors with this script. Also, the scripts are listed only once and in the correct order. Any help as to what is missing would be appreciated. I also tried using JsonResult. But that did not work either.

```html
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddControllersWithViews();
  services.AddKendo();
  services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(o =>
  {
o.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =  ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0); 
}
```

```html
public ActionResult BindGrid([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
  var company = new List<Company>();
  company.Add(new Company
  {
    CompanyId = 102,
    Id = 1,
    Name = "John Smith"
  });
           
DataSourceResult result = company.ToDataSourceResult(request);
return Json(result);        
}
```

```html
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI 
@model IEnumerable<GridPortal.Web.Models.Company>

  <script src="~/lib/kendo/2020.1.406/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/lib/kendo/2020.1.406/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/lib/kendo/2020.1.406/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>


  <div style="width:100%;height:60%">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridPortal.Web.Models.Company>() .Name("BindGridUsingRead") 
.Columns(columns => { columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Width(15).Title("ID").Filterable(false); columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name").Width(30).Filterable(false); columns.Bound(p => p.CompanyId).Title("CompanyID").Width(15).Filterable(false);
      }) .Scrollable() .Pageable() .Filterable(ftp => ftp.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row)) .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true)) .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 100%" }) .Selectable() .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource .Ajax() .Model(model => model.Id(p
      => p.Id)) .ServerOperation(false) .Read(read => read.Action("BindGrid", "Home"))) )
  </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvqoS.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure add the following js and css file in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@{ var kendoVersion = "2020.1.219";}
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/@kendoVersion/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/@kendoVersion/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/@kendoVersion/styles/kendo.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/@kendoVersion/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/@kendoVersion/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/@kendoVersion/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/@kendoVersion/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

And remove the jQuery:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Be sure add the following code in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Adding this helped. Thank you so much.  services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });